# Debian boot disc with a gnu zebra

Tags: linux, boot, installation, debian

How can I build a debian boot disc with GNU Zebra installed on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a Debian system and install GNU Zebra on it. Then you can use [bootcd](http://packages.debian.org/bootcd) to create a bootable CD image of the system.